# Integrating FaceBook, Twitter, Social networks in Android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, social-networking

Integrating Multiple Social networks into Android with a single common Framework or API or JAR

**For iPhone we have ShareKit, which integrates multiple sharing options in one framework.
http://www.getsharekit.com/**

For android i have no idea if something similar exists. I am building an application which shares information to social networks, like some posts and tweets. Its a simple game, where gamers publish updates about their achievements and levels.. etc.. I used Facebook and twitter APIs but they take up lots of memory and difficult to manage. Also i cannot handle them efficiently. Any help on how to integrate them would be appreciated.

I would like to have a few suggestions on this..

Another Example seems PinkelStar

<strike>http://www.pinkelstar.com/</strike>
(Not maintained anymore)

Thanks

Comment: i haven't seen any.. If so i will post here.

Comment: @AndroidKid did sociallib works with you , i also want to integrate sharing links to social media without implementing each one of them individual i want a lib to help me doing that , any advices please ?

Comment: @Bella you can use intents to share the URLs. Its really easy for doing. Provided the user has an app installed in the device for handling it.

Comment: @AndroidKid the link to pinkelstar does not work any more. Seems that the project went off the air?

Comment: Try using google firebase for all social logins. you can also provide your custom logins

Answer (score 32):

> EDIT on 14 July 2012 21.30 IST.
>
> The project is abandoned by the Creator and is no more usable due to
>   changes in Facebook APIs. I contacted the Dev and he is not going to
>   maintain it anymore. I will post any updates. Until then the best
>   option would be to use intents.
>
> Thank you..

I found it after a lot of discussions with many developers.
sociallib is the only reliable one.

https://github.com/sdossick/SocialLib

It allows to integrate

- Facebook
- Twitter
- Google Buzz
- LinkedIn

This is the best solution i have found.. Thanks...

Comment: Above like is not open. I have same problem as you given

Comment: hi the link u gave does not exist now plz refer some other link .i also want the same

Comment: Seems the project is nomore now.  Will post updates..  Thanks.

Comment: @rajpara I think you have to read the big Quote text in ash background.... The project is not available anymore.. So the solution is to use intents.

Answer (score 21):

I know the question is over a year old. However, if you search on Google this question keeps coming up in the results. Thats why I felt the need to provide another answer.

Since June 2012 a nice library called socialauth-android exists to easily integrate the 4 popular social networks (Facebook, Twitter, Myspace, LinkedIn).

I haven't had any hands on experience with this library yet, but it looks very promising. I will post more details once I've played with the library.

Please see [socialauth-android website](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)

Alternative Link : - [GitHub](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android)

Comment: I saw this Library. Its seems quite interesting and Useful.

Comment: Hi , the new version of api now supports 10 providers including yahoo , foursquare. the api now gives functionality to upload images , get feeds and get albums

Comment: I agree, Social-oauth is the best till date. And the support from the community is super great.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe using [ASNE library](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) make your life easier?
Just add dependency to your project:

```
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-facebook:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-twitter:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-googleplus:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-linkedin:0.2.0'
...
}
```

setup and request almost anything!

Answer (score 5):

Android uses an extensible architecture based on Intents. The preferred way is to hook into that framework, instead of trying to support every social network directly in your app as you're asking. One advantage is that new social networks and new APIs will be supported automatically. See:

- [How to share web application with facebook, twitter etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400283/how-to-share-web-application-with-facebook-twitter-etc)

Comment: i need to integrate not just open another application.... Facebook within my application. I don't wanna support all social apps in one.. All in need is to share a small message/status via my app. I don't want the user to navigate away from my app for doing this...

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty old question but I will write a very answer to this. You can easily do this using the CloudRail API.
Supports integration of Facebook, Twitter, G+, Instagram, LinkedIn, Yahoo, Windows Live, GitHub and Slack..
Just have to create an object of each in the same way and get an app key and app secret key. For example

```
Facebook f = new Facebook(this, appKey, appSecret);
f.post(…)
Twitter t = new Twitter(this, appKey, appSecret);
t.post(…)
```

and so on.
[HERE](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/13/The-Ultimate-Guide-To-Social-Login-In-Android-Using-CloudRail?utm_source=quora&utm_medium=answer&utm_term=social_login_cloudrail&utm_content=social_login_cloudrail&utm_campaign=social_login_cloudrail) is a full blog post that shows you how to achieve this. Hope that helps
**DISCLAIMER:** I wrote that post