# How to connect facebook and twitter from android application

Tags: android

I have application which connects facebook and twitter for sharing information for my app. I need help to get API key for facebook and twitter networking. I don't know how to get that key for my android app.

Comment: Duplicate of this post, Check this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076691/integrating-facebook-twitter-social-networks-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For facebook connectivity use following link might it can help you .

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Answer (score 2):

For Twitter, try using
http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html
It has docs, examples etc for you to browse.

Answer (score 0):

For facebook connect example in android

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr